# Fatal error coming while creating a tree

Tags: php, cakephp, select, drop-down-menu

I previously didn't give good information on question.My question is that while creating a Drop down tree in cake php .Cake php throwing this error.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 524288000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 429982192 bytes) in /home/isteam/public_html/upms/app/controllers/tests_controller.php on line 85
```

I tried to increase the limit on run time through php inin function but no sucess.

```
ini_set('memory_limit','2000M');
```

My code table Structure is this

```
|id|parent_id|cat_name|
```

My code is following

```
    function admin_takecat(){
$this->layout=false;
$this->render(false);
Configure::write('debug',2);
 App::import('Model','Category');
$this->cats=new Category();
$firstlevel=$this->cats->find('list',array('fields'=>array('Category.id','Category.cat_name'),'conditions'=>array('Category.parent_id'=>0,'department_id'=>9)));

$dropbox='<select>';
foreach($firstlevel as $id=>$val){
    $dropbox.='<option value='.$id.'>'.$val.'</option>';
    $count=$this->cats->find('count',array('conditions'=>array('Category.parent_id'=>0,'Category.department_id'=>9,'Category.parent_id'=>$id)));
    if($count>0){
    $dropbox=$this->_recursive($id,$dropbox,1);

    }

}
$dropbox.='</select>';
echo $dropbox;



}
    function _recursive($catid,$dropbox,$level){



  App::import('Model','Category');
$this->cats=new Category();
$listcats=$this->cats->find('list',array('fields'=>array('Category.id','Category.cat_name'),'conditions'=>array('Category.parent_id'=>0,'Category.department_id'=>9,'Category.parent_id'=>$catid)));
$mark='';
for($i=1;$i<=1;$i++){
    $mark.='-';

}

foreach($listcats as $id=>$val){
   $dropbox.='<option value='.$id.'>'.$mark.$val.'</option>';
    $count=$this->cats->find('count',array('conditions'=>array('Category.parent_id'=>0,'Category.department_id'=>9,'Category.parent_id'=>$id)));
    if($count>0){
    $dropbox.=$this->_recursive($id,$dropbox,$level+1);

    }


}


return $dropbox;


}
```

Please suggest me what to do..Or any other way for doing this..

Comment: Cake has a [Tree behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1339/Tree) built in; might be worth a look at.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear: You're fetching to much data, the app is running out of memory because of that. And simply increasing the amount of available memory is *not* a fix it is a very sloppy work-around that will break the app on the next server with a more strictly configured memory setting.

As Ross already suggested check the [TreeBehavior](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1339/Tree) or fix your code to return not that much  data by [limiting the recursive level](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) of the associated model records and fields in the find.

Further you should really follow the [CakePHP coding standards](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html) because your code is horrible and confusing to read. I would not accept this code, not as developer and not as client.

You should access data [through model associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) and not use loadModel() to load every model into the controller.

For the dropbox there is the HtmlHelper, to be specific HtmlHelper::input() and HtmlHelper::select().